# How to make view to fix the screen IOS 8?

Tags: ios8, xcode6, storyboard, autolayout

I designed an app, just my first app :) But I'm having issue about fixing the view to the screen. As you can see below in the picture, it has empty spaces from right and bottom. I tried to add constrainst and disable auto layout. I tried to enable just auto layout, and also tried enabling both auto layout and size classes.

Looked up from the internet, yet still couldn't find a such an example that solves my situation.

It shouldn't be that hard since I'm trying to do it for 3 hour. I'd much appreciated if someone can help me to figure it out!

Here is the picture that briefly explains the situation:

[image: view problem, empty spaces at right and bottom]

Thanks!

Comment: study this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: Thanks! I will. I think I found different writing of him but not this, interesting.

Comment: first of all pinned all edges with 0 margin will solve your problem

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm done thanks to @Katoch and his advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the constraints, autolayout, as i tried solve your issue and it is solved by using autolayout. see the screenshot.[image]

Comment: yeah thanks, that was what I did exactly. Still, thanks!